# In python, is it possible to allow a method to change only part of the data member, let the other part constants wrt the method?

Tags: python

For example a class has two data members `a` and `b`.

Two methods `fun1` and `fun2` are defined for this class.

Is it possible to achieve the following safe guard by:

- allow `fun1` to change `a`, and read `b` as a constant, any change on `b` throws an error.
- allow `fun2` to change `b`, and read `a` as a constant, any change on `a` throws an error.

I searched online but couldn't find an answer.